# Kotlin generic type mismatch

Tags: kotlin, generics, migration

Is it possible to accept subclass of a class in generics? It works in Java but unfortunatelly I don't know how to make it work in Kotlin.
Simplified problem:

```
open class Food

class Meat : Food()

interface Animal<T : Food> {
    fun eat(food : T)
}

class Dog : Animal<Meat> {
    override fun eat(food: Meat) {
        // Dog eats meat
    }
}

lateinit var pet : Animal<Food>

fun <T : Food> setAnimal(animal: Animal<T>) {
    pet = animal // DO NOT COMPILE
}
```

I would like to method setAnimal() accept all of the animals, no matter which food it likes, and I would like to keep reference to that animal. I thought Kotlin is 100% compatible with Java but when I try to convert class to Kotlin it doesn't convert well and I have to fix that issue. I read a lot of articles but still have no idea how to make it work.

**EDIT**:
Java code that solves problem but how to do that in Kotlin?

```
public class Test {

    class Food {}

    class Meat extends Food {}

    interface Animal<T extends Food> {
        void eat(T food);
    }

    class Dog implements Animal<Meat> {
        @Override
        public void eat(Meat food) {
            
        }
    }
    
    private Animal animal;

    public void setAnimal(Animal animal) {
        this.animal = animal;
        animal.eat(new Meat());
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**
Sample code which uses out Food, as it was proposed. I've marked line that do not compile.

```
open class Food

class Meat : Food()

interface Animal<T : Food> {
    fun eat(food : T)
}

class Dog : Animal<Meat> {
    override fun eat(food: Meat) {
        // Dog eats meat
    }
}

lateinit var pet : Animal<out Food>


fun <T : Food> setAnimal(animal: Animal<T>) {
    val pet : Animal<out Food> = animal
    pet.eat(Meat()) // DO NOT COMPILE
}
```

Comment: is `pet` and `setAnimal` a global variable or within some class?

Comment: within some class, I wanted to post small piece of code to give a feeling of a problem

Comment: Java analog ```class Food{}
interface Animal<T extends Food> {
    void eat(T food);
}

public class GenericsIssue {
    Animal<Food> pet;
    <T extends Food> void setAnimal(Animal<T> animal) {
        pet = animal;
    }
}
```

won't compile either. You need to manually cast `pet = (Animal<Food>) animal;` (actually you may do the same in Kotlin `pet = animal as Animal<Food>` as well)

Could you provide your original java code?

Comment: I've added Java code to the question

Comment: can you share actual example? `animal.eat(new Meat());` wouldn't make sense if `animal` if of type `Sheep`, shouldn't `eat Meat`. kotlin is just trying to avoid this incorrect behaviour

Comment: Already shared example in main post. This is not a good example but idea is proper in my real scenario. Java allows that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `out` modifier on `pet` variable definition

```
lateinit var pet : Animal<out Food>
```

More information https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I tried this before and unfortunatelly it leads to another issue.

fun <T : Food> setAnimal(animal: Animal<T>) {
    val pet : Animal<out Food> = animal
    pet.eat(Meat()) // DO NOT COMPILE
}

Now it's not possible to call method eat() with Meat() or Food() as an argument. Type mismatch. Required Nothing, found Meat Very strange, any clues?

Comment: I've posted Java code to the question. Still no progress in converting to Kotlin